# Getting wrong time after calculating difference between two Dates

Tags: java, calendar

I want to calculate the difference between a certain date and the current time.

```
 int month = 9;
 int day = 17;
 int year = 2013;

 Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);

 int miliseconds= (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() - calendar.getTimeInMillis());

 System.out.println(msToString(second));

 String msToString(int ms) {
    return (new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")).format(new Date(ms));
 }
```

the output is

13091-13091/? D/GTA: 1970-01-08 15:00:20.287

I want to get the amount of days, hours,minutes and seconds remaining.

What do I wrong?

Comment: isn't your `second` in milliseconds?

Comment: sure, it was in seconds first but I didn´t change the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Joda Time library](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
[Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_period.html) class can help.

```
    int month = 9;
    int day = 17;
    int year = 2013;
    int hour= 0;
    int minute =0;
    int second =0;
    int millisecond = 0;

    DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(); //now
    DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond);

    //assuming dt1 is before dt2:
    Period period = new Period(dt1, dt2, PeriodType.dayTime());

   /*
    periodType.dayTime()):
    Gets a type that defines all standard fields from days downwards.

       days
       hours
       minutes
       seconds
       milliseconds 
   */

    PeriodFormatter periodFormatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            .printZeroAlways()
            .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
            .appendDays().appendSuffix("days ")
            .appendHours().appendSuffix("hours ")
            .appendMinutes().appendSuffix("minutes ")
            .appendSeconds().appendSuffix("seconds ");
            .toFormatter(); 

    System.out.println(periodFormatter.print(period));
```

Answer (score 3):

you could try something like the following method

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;


public class TimeToGoCalculator {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         int month = 8;
         int day = 19;
         int year = 2013;

         Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);

         int timeToGo = (int) (calendar.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis())/1000;

         System.out.println(secondsToString(timeToGo));      
    }

    private static String secondsToString(int seconds) {

        int days = seconds / 24 / 3600;
        int hours = (seconds - (days * 24 * 3600 )) / 3600;
        int minutes = (seconds - (days * 24 * 3600 + hours * 3600)) / 60;
        seconds = (seconds - (days * 24 * 3600 + hours * 3600 + minutes * 60));

        return "The remaining time is "+days+" days, "+hours+" hours, "+minutes+
                " minutes, and "+seconds+" seconds.";
     }

}
```

That should give you the output you're looking for.
Notice that, when creating the GregorianCalendar object, the month is 0-indexed, so September would be = 8.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to use external libraries? Then Joda Time can help you, especially the [Period class](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html).

It has a constructor for two time instants and gives you the difference between the time instants in years/months/days/hours/seconds/milliseconds.

Comment: Yeah, I´m usingn it now =)

Answer (score 0):

Your `second` variable holds an amount of milliseconds between the two dates, not a new date. You need to do some calculation using these milliseconds to get an amount of days, for instance.

You could do something like this:

```
int minutes = second/1000/60; // millis to seconds, seconds to minutes
```

to get an amount of minutes, then convert to hours, and so on.

Comment: renamed it to miliseconds now. yeah, thats exactly what I want, the time between in miliseconds and then I want to convert it in a readable format, day:hour:minute:second which I do with my converter function

Comment: So you can do calculations as I wrote above, but capturing the remainder from each calculation.

Comment: I think the problem was not the conversion itself, but calculating the time difference between two dates